# Vue 3 change reactive object

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have some struggles changing reactive object in Vue 3.
For now my app works like that:

```
 let selected = ref({
            label: items[0].label,
            icon: items[0].icon,
            class: items[0].class,
            component: items[0].component
        });
```

as you see I'm not using reactive here, reactive should look like: `let selected = reactive(items[0]);`

and when I'm changing ref, it works like that:

```
function select(value : any) { //Record<string, any> ) {
      selected.value = value;

      emit('update:modelValue', value);
    }
```

And that works as expected, but when I change to reactive object, I'm removing value from function select, and it's not changing the object. How to fix that?

btw: I'm using TypeScript

Comment: Can you please include the snippet where you attempted to use reactive and it does not work as expected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js 3 - replace/update reactive object without losing reactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732144/vue-js-3-replace-update-reactive-object-without-losing-reactivity) - I had a similar issue and both answers work. So using `reactive` you can use `Object.assign(selected, value)`.