# Why vue compnent property doesn;t update When open it secodnd time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have vue component which data() property `center2` which basicallly `lng,lat` object. This property supposes to update when every location changes. but it get updated for the very first time when I open the component. for every next attempt it only shows default values I have assigned.

data property

```
data()
{
return {
     center2: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
}
}
```

This is how updating it with location inside location watcher

```
  this.center2.lat = Number(location.latitude);
       this.center2.lng = Number(location.longitude);
       console.log('MY',this.center2);
```

I can see in console lat long are coming nicely

What is the reason?

Comment: Can you post a sandbox example with your code?

Comment: Are you using a watcher? And are you looking for update of center2 object?

Comment: Your data is not correct. Isn't it should return an object which contain `center2` as a property

Comment: can you give any example please?

Comment: yes @KurianBenoy something like that

Comment: @SwiftSolutions can you check if this answer helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732144/vue-js-3-replace-update-reactive-object-without-losing-reactivity

Comment: which attribute are you watching?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. You may omit relevant pieces of code that affect this. `data` syntax is wrong.

Comment: @Amaarrockz I am watching center2 object

Answer (score 0):

In Vue2, you might want to try returning `center2` inside data(). It looks like below:

```
data() {
  return {
    center2: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Then `center2` should be updated normally along with the watcher.